# Razor radio button MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

```
<input id="@question.QuestionId" type="radio" value="@question.QuestionDescription" name="@string.Format("name_{0}", question.Group)" checked=@question.IsSelected"checked":false /> @question.QuestionDescription
```

Depending on the question.IsSelected value the checkbox should be selected or not selected.

But regardless of true or false of the IsSelected property Radiobutton is always checked. Can you point where the error in checked attribute please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you give it anything for the `checked` attribute it will be set to checked.  I would optionally add the entire `checked='checked'` value based on the `IsSelected` property, omitting it when the value is false.

```
<input id="@question.QuestionId" type="radio" value="@question.QuestionDescription" name="@string.Format("name_{0}", question.Group)" @(question.IsSelected?"checked='checked'":"") /> @question.QuestionDescription
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this

```
@{
    string checkedAttribute = string.Empty;
    if (question.IsSelected)
    {
        checkedAttribute = "checked=\"checked\"";
    }
}
<input id="@question.QuestionId" type="radio" value="@question.QuestionDescription" name="@string.Format("name_{0}", question.Group)" @checkedAttribute/>
```